# Unable to get hidden values from new window (angular/javascript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a form build in component

**html**

```
 <button type="button" (click)="myForm(i)">
```

**typescript**

```
  myForm(i) {
   let form = document.createElement('form');
   form.setAttribute('action', this.urlAddr);
   form.setAttribute('id', 'test');
   form.setAttribute('target', this.name);
   let method = this.name === 'query' ? 'GET' : 'POST';
   form.setAttribute('method', method);
   let hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'type');
    hiddenField.setAttribute('value', '1');
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    let hiddenFieldTwo = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenFieldTwo.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenFieldTwo.setAttribute('name', 'sas');
    hiddenFieldTwo.setAttribute('value', 'cnt');
    form.appendChild(hiddenFieldTwo);
   let token = document.createElement('input');
   token.setAttribute('id', 'token');
   token.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
   token.setAttribute('name', 'secureToken');
   token.setAttribute('value', this.securityToken);
   form.appendChild(token);
   document.cookie = 'Flag=Y';
   document.body.appendChild(form);
   form.submit();
}
```

now on the 2nd window typescript I tried to retrieve the field 'token' but it kept saying the value is undefined.

**Typescript for new window**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('test'); //this prints but non below prints in new window
    let inputElement: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById('token') as HTMLInputElement;
    let inputTwoElement: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementsByName('secureToken')[0] as HTMLInputElement;
    if (inputElement) { 
      const token: string = inputElement.value;
      console.log('target token =' + token);
    }
    if (inputTwoElement) {
      const token: string = inputTwoElement.value;
      console.log('target tokenTwo =' + token);
    }
}
```

I am confused on why I am not able to get any value. The request is a 'GET' request and the value should able to load from parent window. What am I doing wrong or missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If all of you code is in the same module, try to use ViewChild and ElementRef to get access to the elements as the example below:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <div #myivId>Some text</div>
    `, }) export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('myDivId') myDiv: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.myDiv.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    } }
```

However, if both of the codes you've posted are in different elements, they do not have access to each others DOM. Each of them have their own document before building, all of this will be in a Single Page html after you build.

Side note, if your goal is to share data between components the most formally correct way is to use a Service and that's one of Angulars core advantages.

However, there are various ways you can achieve what you're trying and I would recommend this read: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/